# HTML link does not open

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a test HTML page with a link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="localhost:8080">Log in with TouchLogin</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When clicked, the link does nothing. If I add the `target = "_blank"` attribute, the link opens a new tab, but does not load the URL specified. If I Ctrl-Click it, the link opens fine. What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you add http:// to the beginning of your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you figured it out!

Omitting the http:// will always attempt to open the resource local to where the code originates.

For example, if you're working offline...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="localhost:8080">Log in with TouchLogin</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Will open something like **c://user/parent/localhost:8080**

And working online will open something like **http://parentsite.com/localhost8080**

SO, leave out the http:// when linking to pages on **your site** but include when linking externally. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out upon using a different URL in the `href`(google.com). It did not work without "http://", so I added "http://" to the localhost link and it worked.